# Модификатор static при создании объекта

Tags: java, static, main

Почему при создании объекта вне метода main надо использовать static

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

а при создании объекта в методе main static не нужен

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Но при этом внутри статического метода нельзя создать статический объект

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что сначала иницилизируются поля класса,  а  затем  переменные объекта. Статика  есть   злемент класса,  а переменная есть элемент объекта  наследованного от  класса

Comment: Так делать нельзя, потому что это синтаксическая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

> *Почему при создании объекта вне метода main надо использовать static*

Потому что метод `main` в данном случае объявлен как статический, а статический метод имеет прямой доступ только к статическим полям класса, которым и будет являться экземпляр сканера.

> *а при создании объекта в методе main static не нужен*

В данном случае внутри метода *объявляется* **локальная** переменная для объекта сканера.  К локальным переменным метода (даже если метод статический) модификатор `static` НЕ применяется, так как его основное предназначение -- обозначить *поля/методы*, определённые для всего класса, а не его отдельных экземпляров.

> *Но при этом внутри статического метода нельзя создать статический объект*

*Создать* статический объект ничто не запрещает, а *определить* статическую локальную переменную -- бессмысленно, так как это нарушает определение самого понятия "статический".

```java
private static Scanner scanner;

public static void main(String ... args) {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```